# Two colors on button (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Unselected button looks like this:
[image]

Selected button looks like this: [image]

Why are there two shades of blue?  How do I get rid of that paler shade of blue on the inside?  I want the entire button to be a single solid color.

I've looked at .backgroundColor, thought maybe there was a .foregroundColor, but I can't find what is doing it...

Here is what I'm using:

```
func buttonArrayUpdated(buttonSelected: UIButton) {
    for b in buttonsArray {
        if b == buttonSelected {
            selectedButton = b
            b.isSelected = true
            // default colors for state
            b.backgroundColor = .blue
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
        }
        else {
            b.isSelected = false
            // default colors for state
            b.backgroundColor = .white
            b.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The images you've shown are not from a default `UIButton` ... show the code you're using to change the button appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows to remove that background color:

```
 button.tintColor = .clear
```